# Laravel 5 - Get 2 lists/array from Eloquent query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I can't figure out how to get the following desired output as 2 lists from Eloquent:

```
    // desired output
    $citrusFruitsNames = ["lime","lemon"];
    $citrusFruitsColors = ["green","yellow"];
```

I know I can get the above output which is what I am looking for in 2 separate lists:

```
    $citrusFruitsNames = Fruit::whereType('citrus')->lists('name');
    $citrusFruitsColors = Fruit::whereType('citrus')->lists('color');
```

But I wanted it in one query instead. Here is what I tried along with the outputs so far:

```
    $citrusFruits = Fruit::whereType('citrus')->lists('name');
    // outputs ["lime","lemon"]
    $citrusFruits = Fruit::whereType('citrus')->lists('name', 'color');
    // outputs {"green":"lime","yellow":"lemon"}
    $citrusFruits = Fruit::whereType('citrus')->get(['name', 'color']);
    // outputs [{"name":"lime","color":"green"},{"name":"lemon","color":"yellow"}]
```

How can I get the desired output in one query, and separate the lists/arrays to match the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, `lists()` is a method on the collection, so you can retrieve the data in one step and create the arrays in another:

```
$fruit = Fruit::whereType('citrus')->get(['name', 'color']); // just get() works as well
$citrusFruitsNames = $fruit->lists('name');
$citrusFruitsColors = $fruit->lists('color');
```

**Note** that with Laravel 5.1, `lists` actually returns a new collection and not an array. In some scenarios that might not matter, but if you really want to get just an array, use `all()` afterwards:

```
$fruit->lists('name')->all();
```